# NoClassDefFoundError exception in Java (com.ingrian.security.nae.NAESessionInterface)

Tags: java

I am getting the following exception but I am not exactly sure what am I missing in my project. I couldn't find any proper resource about it. I assumed it could be because of the JRE version. Previously I was using 1.8 and then I switched back to 1.6 but it didn't work. Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ingrian/security/nae/NAESessionInterface
    at mig.eis.client.filter.EISPolicyDecryptFilter.configureSafenetProvider(EISPolicyDecryptFilter.java:49)
    at mig.eis.client.filter.EISPolicyDecryptFilter.<init>(EISPolicyDecryptFilter.java:45)
    at BaseTest.createConfiguration(BaseTest.java:72)
    at TestBilling.<init>(TestBilling.java:31)
    at TestBilling.main(TestBilling.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ingrian.security.nae.NAESessionInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CLASSPATH is missing one, or more, libraries required by the code you are trying to run.  You need to find what library (usually a .jar file) contains the class `com.ingrian.security.nae.NAESessionInterface` and add it to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: But i don't see any jar by this name.

Comment: That is the name of a class.  The jar file could be named anything.  (a jar file is very similar to a zip file)  I have not heard of that one, so I can't suggest and likely names.